# Oracle SQL connect_by_root and subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

For the past few days I'm working on a solution for my assignment and I just can't seem to find an answer.

Introduction: suppose we have a single table called **People**. Each person has three fields: `name` , `boss` and `position`. `name` is a primary key, `position` just a string and `boss` as a foreign key points to a different person's `name`. It creates a ordinary tree like Person1 -> Person2 -> Person3 -> Person4 , where Person4 would be a highest boss and Person1 being the root. For the simplicity let's assume that nobody has more than 3 bosses, and Person4 is the head boss (the only person with `boss` equal to `null`.)

Example paths:

Person7 -> Person4

Person6 -> Person8 -> Person4

Person2 -> Person8 -> Person4

So my assignment says: *create a query which displays in hierarchical order names of each boss for every person with `position` equal to "Worker" or "Manager" **using only tree operations (connect by, connect_by_root etc.) and subqueries***

The output table has to consist of 5 columns:

```
Name | Position | Boss 1 | Boss 2 | Boss 3
```

If any boss column would be null, then I should insert some whitespaces.

This is my query so far:

```
select  
  case    
    when l = 1 then name else '    ' end as "Name",
  position,
  case 
    when l = 2 then name else '    ' end as "Boss 1",
  case
    when l = 3 then name else '    ' end as "Boss 2",
  case 
    when l = 4 then name else '    ' end as "Boss 3"    
from (
  select
    connect_by_root position as position, 
    level as l,
    name 
  from 
    People
  connect by prior
    boss = name
  start with 
    position = 'Worker'
    or position = 'Manager'
  );
```

It kinda does the trick, but each level of the tree is a new row, that's something I have to avoid. I know why this query produces result like that but I have no idea how to make it traverse the tree without creating new row on each step.

My result:

```
Name |Position|Boss 1|Boss 2|Boss 3

JOHN    WORKER                  
        WORKER  HENRY               
        WORKER          PETER       
TERRY   WORKER                      
        WORKER  PETER               
ALICE   WORKER                  
        WORKER  PETER               
BILL    MANAGER                     
        MANAGER JAMES               
        MANAGER         PETER
```

This is the result I want to achieve:

```
Name |Position|Boss 1|Boss 2|Boss 3

JOHN    WORKER  HENRY  PETER        

TERRY   WORKER  PETER                   

ALICE   WORKER  PETER                   

BILL    MANAGER JAMES  PETER
```

Is there any solution **without** using sophisticated functions like Pivot to make it work?

Comment: Just `max` or `min` functions. And replace `... name else '    ' end ...` with `... name else null end ...`

Comment: These functions into subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like this (I have no source data to check):

```
select  
  root_name as "Name",
  max(position),
  max(case when l = 2 then name else null end) as "Boss 1",
  max(case when l = 3 then name else null end) as "Boss 2",
  max(case when l = 4 then name else null end) as "Boss 3"    
from (
  select
    connect_by_root position as position, 
    connect_by_root name as root_name, 
    level as l,
    name 
  from 
    People
  connect by prior
    boss = name
  start with 
    position = 'Worker'
    or position = 'Manager'
  )
group by root_name;
```

Comment: You're missing a group by clause, plus this is a form of pivoting, which I don't think the OP was particularly wanting to do.

Comment: @Boneist Oh, thanks! I tried to make minimal corrections in original query.

Comment: Works like a charm, now I need to think about a solution. What does `max` function do here? Is it just a workaround to be able to `group by` root_name? Does it do something like "pick max from null and name" thus always returning name?

Comment: @Karatte "Does it do something like "pick max from null and name" thus always returning name?" - Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this without any pivots etc needed, purely by using `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`, `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` and `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`, plus judicious use of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
WITH people AS (SELECT 'JOHN' name, 'WORKER' position, 'HENRY' boss FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'HENRY' name, 'CFO' position, 'PETER' boss FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'TERRY' name, 'WORKER' position, 'PETER' boss FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'ALICE' name, 'WORKER' position, 'PETER' boss FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'JAMES' name, 'CIO' position, 'PETER' boss FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'FRED' name, 'MANAGER' position, NULL boss FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'BILL' name, 'MANAGER' position, 'JAMES' boss FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'PETER' name, 'CEO' position, 'FRED' boss FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your people table with some sample data in it
-- you wouldn't need the above, just use the query below:
SELECT connect_by_root name AS name,
       connect_by_root position AS position,
       regexp_substr(sys_connect_by_path(boss, '>'), '[^>]+', 1, 1) boss1,
       regexp_substr(sys_connect_by_path(boss, '>'), '[^>]+', 1, 2) boss2,
       regexp_substr(sys_connect_by_path(boss, '>'), '[^>]+', 1, 3) boss3
FROM   people
WHERE  connect_by_isleaf = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR boss = name
START WITH position IN ('WORKER', 'MANAGER');

NAME  POSITION BOSS1 BOSS2 BOSS3
----- -------- ----- ----- -----
ALICE WORKER   PETER FRED  
BILL  MANAGER  JAMES PETER FRED
FRED  MANAGER              
JOHN  WORKER   HENRY PETER FRED
TERRY WORKER   PETER FRED
```

`CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` determines whether the row is a leaf row (`1`) or not (`0`). Therefore, like you can identify the root value by using `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`, you can tell which row is an end row by using `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF`.

`SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` generates a path of all the values that it's got to so far. So, on the leaf rows, it will contain all the necessary values. We can then parse this generated string to get the first, second, etc part that doesn't contain the path delimiter.